# Generate keywords using Apache Spark and mllib

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, tf-idf, keyword-search

I wrote code like this:

```
val hashingTF = new HashingTF()

val tfv: RDD[Vector] = sparkContext.parallelize(articlesList.map { t => hashingTF.transform(t.words) })
tfv.cache()

val idf = new IDF().fit(tfv)
val rate: RDD[Vector] = idf.transform(tfv)
```

How to get top 5 keywords from the "rate" RDD for each articlesList item?

**ADD:**

articlesList contains objects:

```
case class ArticleInfo (val url: String, val author: String, val date: String, val keyWords: List[String], val words: List[String])
```

words contains all words from article.

I do not understand the structure of rate, in the documentation says:

```
@return an RDD of TF-IDF vectors
```

Comment: I don't think you've provided enough information about what is in articlesList, or what ends up in rate. But probably you want rate.top(5) for some suitable ordering?

Comment: If words only contains distinct terms, then the computed term frequency of all terms will be the same, since each term only occurs once in a list of distinct terms.

Comment: Sorry, all words aren't distinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is:

```
    (articlesList, rate.collect()).zipped.foreach { (art,tfidf) =>
  val keywords = new mutable.TreeSet[(String, Double)]
  art.words.foreach { word =>
      val wordHash = hashingTF.indexOf(word)
      val wordTFIDF = tfidf.apply(wordHash)

      if (keywords.size == KEYWORD_COUNT) {
        val minimum = keywords.minBy(_._2)
        if (minimum._2 < wordHash) {
          keywords.remove(minimum)
          keywords.add((word,wordTFIDF))
        }
      } else {
        keywords.add((word,wordTFIDF))
      }
    }

    art.keyWords = keywords.toList.map(_._1)
}
```